# incorporate lapply in my function. recursion?

Tags: r, function, lapply

Suppose I have an R function:

```
x <- function(x) {
  x <- substr(x, 1, 1)
  return(x)
}
```

If I run

```
x(abc)
```

I will get

```
[1] "a"
```

In order to allow my function to run a list, i.e. `a = list('aas', 'cvs', 'mmm')`

I could use 'lapply' function

```
lapply(a, x)
```

But how to incorporate the lapply() function into my function in order to allow my function directly run a list?

i.e.:

```
x(a)
```

Comment: your function already works on a vector of strings, try `x(c('abc', 'def')`.

Comment: Why do you need `lapply` when `x(a)` will do the job?

Comment: @maRmat, MKR, it is just an example. I want to know how to incorporate lapply in a function, and call this function.

Comment: you can use `Vectorize()` to create a new function that is a vectorised version of your initial function. It will create a new function that is basically a lapply of your function.

Comment: did not check this comment. Hence, deleted my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following trick:

```
fun <- function(x) {
    if (is.list(x)) {
        return(lapply(x, fun))
    }
  x <- substr(x, 1, 1)
  return(x)
}
```

If you want the function to return a character vector rather than a list, replace `lapply` with `sapply`. If you want it to also accept a vector as input, change the condition `is.list(x)` to `length(x) > 1`.

Comment: @Jordi, Thanks a lot.  Is this called recursion?

Comment: Glad it helps! Yes, you can call this recursion in the sense that the function refers to itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
new_function <- function(x) {
  lapply(x, substr, 1, 1)
}
```